# iOS 15 - UItableView top padding issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, ios15

I updated my iPhone to iOS 15 and Xcode to 13 version and now my app have a weird padding on top in all screens that has a tableView.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of research, I founded the answer in Apple developer documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3750914-sectionheadertoppadding?language=objc

So, to solve this problem I added this code in all screen that I was using UITableView:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
   tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = .zero
}
```

With this code the gap goes away.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove this top padding in all views, you can call this code in AppDelegate:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = .zero
}
```

Comment: Objc variant of the above:     `if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) { [[UITableView appearance] setSectionHeaderTopPadding:CGFLOAT_MIN]; }`

Answer (score 2):

The below code is fixed my issue

```
 if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = .init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
    }
```